# Cassandra Create Table/CF latency

Tags: python, cassandra, cql

I'm trying to create a platform for a benchmark I'm running for a client that includes Cassandra as a database    for massive write-throughput load.
There's a huge amount of metrics (time series) to store and figured each metric should be stored as a CQLTable / Column Family.
First problem is that creating them all (~10M metrics) takes days (running a 4-nodes culster).
I tried using executemany (python cql) for bulking, but 'service-time' of latency is about the same.
Can anyone advise on a better way of doing that ?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't create a separate column family for each - 10M column families is far too many, since there are fixed resources taken by each CF.

You would probably be better off putting them in a single CF.  You could add the metric name as a component of a composite primary key e.g.

```
create table metrics (
    metric text,
    day timestamp,
    time timestamp,
    value text,
    primary key ((metric, day))
);
```

The day field is there to shard the metrics by day so they don't all end up in the same row for a given metric.